# Github workflow automation

Tags: git, github, github-projects

I try to automate workflow in my GitHub project kanban board.

The goal is: when the issue is closed and card located in "Closed" column I want to get notification via email that this issue was closed 30 days ago and I maybe want to do something with it.

I checked in Github workflow documentation, there is an event:

```
on:
  project_card:
    types: moved
```

But it will not work in my case. I need to specify that this card is closed and located in "Closed" column.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "closed" activity type in the ["Automating your workflow with GitHub Actions / events  / Project Card](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#project-card-event-project_card) section.
Which seems logical if "closed" is considered as a status, not an activity for a project card.

There is a "closed" activity type for issues though, which means you might monitor issues instead, considering an [issue event](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/)  comes with `project_card["column_name"]` attribute.
It is the name of the column that the card is listed in.